# Yii ClistView pagination not working

Tags: yii, pagination

My Clistview Pagination is not working properly.I tried every thing but still not getting success.Here is my model function:

```
public function getallone()
{
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->select   =   "t.id"; 
    $criteria->condition = "t.featured=1 AND t.status = 1";
            return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
                'pagination' => array('pageSize' => 25),

    ));
}
```

Am still getting only 10 items per page but i want 25.I tried to 2 items but its also not working. Whats wrong with that?Didnt find.

And this is my view code:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
        'dataProvider'=>$model->getallone(),
        'itemView'=>'_allone',

        'enablePagination' => true,
        )); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shoud try this for better pagination option

```
$condition='type=:type';
$dataArray[':type']=$type;
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('modelname', array(
        'criteria'=>array(
         'select'=>'*',
            'condition'=>$condition,
            'params'=>$dataArray,
            'order'=>'id DESC',
            'offset'=>($page-1)*$limit,
            'limit'=>$limit,
         ),
        'pagination'=>array(
            'pageSize'=>$limit,

    ),
    ));

  $totalActivity= $dataProvider->getTotalItemCount();
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveDataProvider for reference

Comment: where's `$limit` declared?

Comment: limit you can set as per your need, i just added structure of pagination.

Answer (score 1):

try and use `CArrayDataProvider`

here is how do it:

```
public function actionIndex() {
        $command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand("
            SELECT u.id as u_id, u.link as u_link, u.title as u_title, u.description as u_description, u.public as u_public, u.created as u_created, u.status as u_status, w.id as w_id, w.domain as w_domain, w.status as w_status
            from url as u
            left join website as w
                on w.id = u.website_id
            where u.title!='null' and u.status = 1 and w.status = 1 and u.public = 1;
            ");
        $news = $command->queryAll();
        $dataProvider = new CArrayDataProvider($news, array(
                    'id' => 'user',
                    'keyField' => 'u_id',
                    'sort' => array(
                        'defaultOrder' => 'u_id desc',
                    ),
                    'pagination' => array(
                        'pageSize' => 10,
                    ),
                ));
        $model_website = Website::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('status' => 1), array('limit' => 30, 'order' => 'id desc'));
        $this->render('index', array(
            'model_website' => $model_website,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ));
    }
```

and the clistview:

```
    $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'template' => "{summary}\n{pager}\n{items}\n{summary}\n{pager}",
        'itemView' => '_index',
        'pager' => array(
            'maxButtonCount' => 10,
        ),
            )
    );
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but its creating more complexity in the code,its not the answer am looking for as am said earlier that i already tried all( which includes carray, csql) data providers.